# Conditional variance and expectancy of two independent poisson variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, poisson-distribution, variance

Le $\ X \sim Pois(5) , Y \sim Pois(10) $ both independent. Suppose I draw and rectangle with width $\ X $ and length $\ Y $. Suppose the circumference of the rectangle is $\ 28 $ what is $\ Var(X) $ ?
First I set another variable $\ S $ to be the circumference . So $\ S = 2X + 2Y $

$$\ Var(X) = E[Var(X|S=28)] + Var(E[X|S = 28])  = \\E[Var(X|Y=14-X)] + Var(E[X|Y=14-X]) $$

I'm really having hard time grasping this concept, what is $\ E[X|S = 28 ] $ ? and what is the variance of such variable? Maybe I should set new variable $\ T = (X|S=28) $ and try to understand what distribution it has?

Comment: You are looking for $\text{Var}(X)$ or $\text{Var}(X|X+Y=14)?$ They are totally different. Also the law of tatal variance should be $$\text{Var}(X)=E[\text{Var}(X|S)]+\text{Var}(E[X|S]).$$ (It is different from yours.) You can't calculate it from $E[X|S=28]$ and $\text{Var}(X|S=28)$ since they are constants. And you cannot also get $\text{Var}(X|S=28)$ and $E[X|S=28]$ from $E[\text{Var}(X|S)]$ or $\text{Var}(E[X|S])$.

Comment: I'm looking for $\ Var(X|X+Y=14) $

Answer (score 1):

Observe that for $k=0,1,2,\dots$ we have the following conditional probabilities : $$p_k=P(X=k\mid S=28)=\frac{P(X=k\wedge S=28)}{P(S=28)}=\frac{P(X=k\wedge X+Y=14)}{P(X+Y=14)}$$

Here $\sum_kp_k=1$ so we can speak of a distribution.

In that context there is a variance which can be written as:$$\sum_kp_kk^2-\left(\sum_kp_kk\right)^2$$This on base of the general identity $\mathsf{Var}(Z)=\mathbb EZ^2-(\mathbb EZ)^2$.

This is actually the variance that you are after and can be denoted as $\mathsf{Var}(X\mid S=28)$.

Further here $\sum_kp_kk$ is the expectation and can be denoted as $\mathbb E[X\mid S=28]$. So it is not a random variable but a real number, so that your question "what is the variance of such variable" can only be answered with: its variance is $0$.

Comment: Why $\ \sum_k pk = 1 $ it is not clear to me?

Comment: Because  $\sum_kP (X=k\wedge S=28)=P (S=28) $.

Comment: And why is the variance is $\ 0 $ ? that doesn't make any sense. I mean if $\ X + Y =14 $ each of the variable may get any value between $\ 0 $ to $\ 14 $ ...

Comment: Not the variance that you are asked to find is $0$. However you wondered "what is the variance of $E[X\mid S=28]$?" That one is $0$ because $E[X\mid S=28]$ is a real number, so is at most a degenerated random variable.